# How to detect if an element is outside of its container's width?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect an element that is completely (not partially) outside of a specific containers width?

For example, I have the following:

```
<div id="content">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
      <p>This is a paragraph</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

My `content` div has the width of 100%, and my `p` tags are animated to scroll across the screen. How can I detect if they are outside of the `content` div so that I can remove them?

Testing for outside of the viewport is not an option since my `content` div also has a container.

Comment: Im assuming that you want to detect that its outside of the wrapper because you cant make it fit into the container right?? have you tried using box-sizing: border-box css?

Comment: @ncubica - My `wrapper` div has not width styling, only the `content` div has width styling. And no, haven't tried that actually. How can that detect if it if outside of the `content` div? Basically, I am trying to remove the elements if they go outside of the `content`.

Comment: How about using [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), [.width()](https://api.jquery.com/width/) and [.height()](https://api.jquery.com/height/) to compare the positions?

Comment: @JosefOttosson - I attempted to use `width()` with `.position().left` and `.position().right` together, although I had no luck. Haven't tried `offset()`. Any chance of an example?

Comment: @JosefOttosson - Don't need to test for height, only need to test for width.

Comment: provide us a fiddle to work with

Comment: How your `p tags` goes outside of `content`? They should be inside `content`, Right?

Comment: @fizzix Could you elaborate "had no luck"? I'm still not sure what you're trying to achieve. Could you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you have so far?

Comment: Thinking about this - wouldn't an overflow-x hidden work for you? Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/Pc9SJ/1/ - that way, it should auto-hide when it overflows out of the holding div

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the `getBoundingClientRect()` method should work well. Made a better working example using the paragraphs, here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5eTw/3/).

```
function HorizontallyBound(parentDiv, childDiv) {
    var parentRect = parentDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
    var childRect = childDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

    return parentRect.left >= childRect.right || parentRect.right <= childRect.left;
}

var bound = HorizontallyBound(document.getElementById("parent"), document.getElementById("some_paragraph"));
```

Or using jQuery with the same concept:

```
function HorizontallyBound($parentDiv, $childDiv) {
    var parentRect = $parentDiv[0].getBoundingClientRect();
    var childRect = $childDiv[0].getBoundingClientRect();

    return parentRect.left >= childRect.right || parentRect.right <= childRect.left;
}

var bound = HorizontallyBound($("#parent"), $("#some_paragraph"));
```

Updated my answer because I reread that you're checking if the child is **completely** outside of the parent, not partially.

Comment: I really think this would work the best, but I am non-stop getting errors. Any chance of a jQuery example?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you could try something I use on one of my own sites:

```
var $elem = $('#preview_link_box'),
    top = $elem.offset().top,
    left = $elem.offset().left,
    width = $elem.width(),
    height = $elem.height();


if (left + width > $(window).width()) {
    console.log("Looks like its outside the viewport...");
}
```

Comment: A fiddle would be helpful

Comment: Can you provide me with a example of your animation code? Mine is aimed at when you have an item floating, loaded when you hover over another element (this stops it from overflowing out of the page, as you can "pull" it back to the left/right a bit more). Bit hard to give a working fiddle without knowing a bit more on how you are animating yours though :)

Comment: Hey Andrew. Unfortunately I cannot since I am using a ton of other libraries. This of a stock ticker bar or a horizontal news scroll. I have many elements scrolling across the page, and when they leave the container, I need to destroy them and load another element at the end of the scroll feed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to do, but I tried to create something similar.  It's a really simple idea as far as the logic.  [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/FGwDt/)

Basically the idea was to use the width of `#content` div and slide the `p` elements over until it reached that number and then remove them.

```
var width = $('.wrapper p:first').width(),
    i     = 0, 
    $me   = $('.wrapper p');

// slide paragraphs over to the left, once out of bounds they are removed
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (i == -width) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        $me.remove();
    }
    $me.css('margin-left', --i);
}, 10);
```