# How to keep an image from leaving a area in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a program that has a user move an image of a car to avoid obstacles moving down on the image. I am able to move the car up, down, left, and right. How exactly do I keep the image from leaving the box I created?

I also moved the image position so it looks right to the border. Is there an easier way to have it line up with the box?

```js
//init object globally
var objImage = null;

function init() {
  objImage = document.getElementById("car");
  objImage.style.position = 'relative';
  objImage.style.left = '748px';
  objImage.style.top = '-405px';
}

function getKeyAndMove(e) {
  var key_code = e.which || e.keyCode;
  if (key_code == 37) {
    moveLeft();
  } else if (key_code == 38) {
    moveUp();
  } else if (key_code == 39) {
    moveRight();
  } else if (key_code == 40) {
    moveDown();
  }
}

function moveLeft() {
  objImage.style.left = parseInt(objImage.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}

function moveUp() {
  objImage.style.top = parseInt(objImage.style.top) - 5 + 'px';
}

function moveRight() {
  objImage.style.left = parseInt(objImage.style.left) + 5 + 'px';
}

function moveDown() {
  objImage.style.top = parseInt(objImage.style.top) + 5 + 'px';
}
window.onload = init;
```

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 2.8em;
  text-align: center;
}

#Screen {
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px gray;
}

#car {
  width: 50px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div onkeydown='getKeyAndMove(event)'>
  <h1>Drive your car with arrow keys</h1>
  <div id="Screen" width="400px" height="400px"></div>
  <img id="car" tabindex="0" src='https://via.placeholder.com/120'>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll have to get the boundaries of each element and compare them. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22829188/how-to-detect-if-an-element-is-outside-of-its-containers-width.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your js code, corrected html changed and css.

1. Insert your `img` tag inside `Screen` id;
2. Specify the rule `position: relative` for `#Screen` in css;
3. Insert this line `objImageBox = document.getElementById("Screen")`, and pass the `absolute position` inside the `init()` function;
4. For each button I had to write an `if` condition (you can familiarize yourself with the code);
5. For the right and bottom parts, I had to calculate the `width/height` of the box and the `width/height` of the moving object.

```js
//init object globally
        var objImage= null;
        function init(){
            objImage=document.getElementById("car"); 
            objImageBox=document.getElementById("Screen");
            objImage.style.position='absolute';
            objImage.style.left='0';
            objImage.style.top='0';
            

        }
        
        function getKeyAndMove(e){              
            var key_code=e.which||e.keyCode;
            if(key_code == 37){
                moveLeft();
            }
            else if(key_code == 38){
                moveUp();
            }
            else if(key_code == 39){
                moveRight();
            }
            else if(key_code == 40){
                moveDown();
            }
        }
        function moveLeft(){
            objImage.style.left=parseInt(objImage.style.left)-5 +'px';
            if (objImage.style.left < '0') {
              objImage.style.left = '0';
            } else {}
        }
        function moveUp(){
            objImage.style.top=parseInt(objImage.style.top)-5 +'px';
            if (objImage.style.top < '0') {
              objImage.style.top = '0';
            } else {}
        }
        function moveRight(){
            objImage.style.left=parseInt(objImage.style.left)+5 +'px';
            if (parseInt(objImage.style.left) > objImageBox.clientWidth - objImage.clientWidth) {
              objImage.style.left = objImageBox.clientWidth - objImage.clientWidth + 'px';
            } else {}
        }
        
        function moveDown(){
            objImage.style.top=parseInt(objImage.style.top)+5 +'px';
            if (parseInt(objImage.style.top) > objImageBox.clientHeight - objImage.clientHeight) {
              objImage.style.top = objImageBox.clientHeight - objImage.clientHeight + 'px';
            } else {}
        }
        window.onload=init;
```

```css
h1{
        font-size: 2.8em;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #Screen{
        border: 2px solid white;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        padding-left: 0;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        display: block;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px gray;
        position: relative;
    }
    #car{
        width: 50px;
        height: 120px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body onkeydown='getKeyAndMove(event)'>
    <h1>Drive your car with arrow keys</h1>
    <div id="Screen" width="400px" height="400px" >
    
    <img id="car"  tabindex="0" src='https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/600/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg'>
    
    </div>
    <!-- <img id="car" tabindex="5"/> -->
    
</body>
</html>
```